# User-Defined Sounds for Apple Push Notifications?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, audio

Is there any way to for a user to choose the alert sound or ring tone upon receiving a push notification from my app, or do all possible sounds needs to be packaged with the app bundle and be determined from the push server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For push notifications as well as for local notification Apple writes so:

> **Sound** The name of a sound file in the application bundle. The sound in this
>   file is played as an alert. If the sound file doesn’t exist or default
>   is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played. The
>   audio must be in one of the audio data formats that are compatible
>   with system sounds; see “Preparing Custom Alert Sounds” for details.

Based on this I would say yes, the sound file has to be in your application's bundle and you can't send it dynamically. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected.  You would hope Apple would come up with a way in a near future iOS release to let users define their own sounds per app.

Comment: I doubt so, they are too paranoiac about the royalty of ringing tones and about importing external binary data (sounds files) to your application... create a nice portfolio of music that the user can choose from and embed it in the application bundle if it is important for your business.